# PhpStorm / WebIdea / WebStorm not suggesting the correct code completion in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, phpstorm, webstorm

I don't use JavaScript very often, I'm a C# developer, so please be patient..

PhpStorm doesn't solve the `create` function of the tinymce class. Neither that I use it inside a js file, neither that I create a TypeScript. I've spent a few hours trying to understand how it works but I have no idea what to try now.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have tinymce package installed? What does package.json look like?

Comment: @Oksana: sorry for the delay. Yes, it's installed in the libraries, I don't have a package.json, there is only the tsconfig.json. https://i.imgur.com/9GRN7i1.png

Comment: Do you have tinymce library code in your project? Is it in the node_modules folder or elsewhere?